# R Shiny "R_ZIPCMD" path zipping error

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, zip, shiny-server

I have 2 running apps on my R Shiny server in Ubuntu 16.04. Both do some data manipulation (e.g. cleaning, joining tables, etc.) and then dump the outputs as an Excel file with a function something like,

```
dumpExcel <- function(matched, non_matched=NULL, fileName, out_format='xlsx') {
    if (out_format == 'xlsx') {
        library(openxlsx)
        output <- createWorkbook()
        addWorksheet(output, "matched")
        if (!(is.null(non_matched))) { addWorksheet(output, "non_matched") }
        writeData(output,"matched", matched, colNames = T)
        if (!(is.null(non_matched))) { writeData(output,"non_matched", non_matched, colNames = T) }
        FileName = fileName
        saveWorkbook(output, FileName, overwrite = T)
        return(output)
    } else if (out_format == 'csv') {
        write.csv(matched, gsub('.xlsx', '.csv', fileName), row.names=F)
    }
}
```

For the first app, this function works perfectly. For the second one, it was working perfectly, but somehow it isn't now and throws the error below,

```
Error in : zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R.
     Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows. If the "Rtools\bin" directory does not appear in Sys.getenv("PATH") please add it to the system PATH 
     or set this within the R session with Sys.setenv("R_ZIPCMD" = "path/to/zip.exe")
```

I've tried to add the line `Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD = "/usr/bin/zip")` beforehand, it didn't work. How come does this app throw this error whereas the other one in the same server/machine is working perfectly?

Any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD = "/usr/bin/zip")` in server.R (after loading libraries, and before the `shinyServer(function(...` block. That works for me.

Comment: I was really hoping that this would work. Unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it's a memory issue. Free memory was about ~200MB, increased it to >1GB and the problem is solved.